# Unable to install latest git on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, software-installation, git

I have checked [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/568596/216985) and followed the same steps.

My system throws

```
git is already the newest version.
```

But when i do `git --version` it shows

```
git version 1.8.1.2
```

I need to install git >= 1.9.4.

I have several tutorials and all of them are suggesting above method but it doesn't work.

**Edit:**

Output of `apt-cache policy git`

```
git:
  Installed: 1:2.4.6-0ppa1~ubuntu14.04.1
  Candidate: 1:2.4.6-0ppa1~ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 1:2.4.6-0ppa1~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.1 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     1:1.9.1-1 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     1:1.8.3.2-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
```

`which git` gives

```
/usr/local/bin/git
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy git`

Comment: Add the output of `which git`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version in Trusty is 1.9.1. To install 2.1.4  you need Vivid. To get version 2.4.6 you have to wait for Wily.

To install packages from [this](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA  you need at least Lucid.

Based on the output of

```
apt-cache policy git
```

you have installed version 2.4 6

I assume, either you don't use `/usr/bin/git` or the file was overwritten.

To resolve the first point, check the output of `which git`

If the output **isn't** `/usr/bin/git`, remove the file, because you want to use the binary from the git package.

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/git
```

and for the second point

```
sudo apt-get install -reinstall git
```

Comment: `which git` gives `/usr/local/bin/git` but if add `/usr/bin` at the beginning of `$PATH` other programmes are not working?