# Problems after git installation from source

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, git

I have the following problem.

I have installed latest git version from source, but maybe I have done something  wrong, because now when I am trying to install/uninstall any stuff using `apt-get` I get the following message:

```
You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

git-core: Depends: git (> 1:1.7.0.2) but it is not going to be installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Well, after `sudo apt-get -f install`, it proposes to install git:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
git
```

and after typing 'Y' I get another error:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/git_2%3a2.3.6-1avh1~lucid1_amd64.deb (--unpack):

trying to overwrite '/etc/bash_completion.d/git', which is also in package git-core 2:2.3.6-1avh1~lucid1

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/git_2%3a2.3.6-1avh1~lucid1_amd64.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `apt-get purge git.*` then either reinstall your self-built git dpkgs, or follow the instructions in the other question to install the PPA (recommended).

Answer (score 0):

Try 
apt-get purge git

Then instead of compiling from source, you can add another repo that will have the latest available git, which is explained here, allowing you to simply use apt-get install git after adding the new repo

[How do I install the latest version of Git with apt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/568591/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-git-with-apt?lq=1)