# how do I install the latest version of git with sudo apt-get build-dep?

Tags: 14.04, apt

I am trying to resolve an issue following the steps of these instructions here [gnutls-handshake-error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186847/error-gnutls-handshake-failed-when-connecting-to-https-servers). There is a step that wants me to execute this command:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep git
```

When I execute this command for some reason, I always get `git version 1.9.1` I want version `2.10.1` Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: That's what 14.04 has: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/git. Use a PPA if you want to use `apt` to get a newer version of git http://askubuntu.com/a/568596/158442