# How to work around build dependencies with disparate epoch numbers?

Tags: apt, package-management, launchpad

I have [a build on Launchpad](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/250352502/buildlog_ubuntu-trusty-i386.golang_2%3A1.5.1-0ubuntu2.1~ubuntu14.04.1~ppa1_BUILDING.txt.gz) that is failing for reasons that escape me.

The package clearly lists the build dependencies as:

```
Merged Build-Depends: ..., golang (>= 1:1.4~) | gccgo-5, ...
Filtered Build-Depends: ..., golang (>= 1:1.4~) | gccgo-5, ...
```

Unless I am missing something, this means either a version of `golang` >= 1.4 must be installed **or** `gccgo-5` must be installed.

But APT does neither of those things. Further down, we see:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ... golang-go ...
0 upgraded, 29 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 26.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 139 MB of additional disk space will be used.
...
Get:27 [...] trusty/universe golang-go i386 2:1.2.1-2ubuntu1 [7148 kB]
```

How on earth does `golang` 1.2 satisfy the build dependency? What's going on here? What am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit:** as pointed out in the comments, the problem revolves around the epoch numbers. My question now becomes: *what can I do to work around this?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do some packages have extra numbers on the front of their version string?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/441879/why-do-some-packages-have-extra-numbers-on-the-front-of-their-version-string)

Comment: Notice the version numbers: `1:1.4~` and `2:1.2.1-2ubuntu1`. `1:` and `2:`. Somebody forgot to account for epoch numbers.

Comment: Hmm... that would explain it, alright. I've retitled the question and added some clarification to the post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once epoch numbers come into play, you cannot meaningfully request anything other than exact version from an older epoch as a depedency. `>= 1:1.4` will be satisfied by any package from a newer epoch, even `2:0.1`. You could use exact matches (`== 1:1.4`), but I doubt that's what you want.

Since all currently supported versions of Ubuntu have [`golang` packages versioned with the new epoch](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=golang), it's time you moved to it as well. [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/golang) also uses the new epoch. So, at the moment, it looks like only unofficial sources will even have a `1:`-versioned `golang` package.

Comment: I finally ended up doing exactly what you described and changed the `1` to a `2` in the `Build-Depends` field. Works now.