# Create a debian package with dependency to older version of python-cherrypy3 package

Tags: apt, package-management, deb

I have a program with a debian package in my personal repository that depends on python-cherrypy3. However, version 3.5.0 of python-cherrypy3 shipped with Ubuntu 16.04 has a serious unfixed bug that stops my program from creating an HTTPS web server. I have put version 3.2.2 of `python-cherrypy3` on my personal repository. Then put a

```
Depends: python-cherrypy3 (<< 3.2.5)
```

in `debian/control` file of my package. The bug starts from 3.2.5 version of cherrypy, so every version lower than this version is acceptable. But Ubuntu 16.04 `apt-get` cannot resolve the dependency and still prefers the newer version 3.5.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 my-package : Depends: python-cherrypy3 (< 3.2.5)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I do `apt-get install python-cherrypy3=3.2.2` and install older version of cherrypy from my repository, then the installation of my package works fine. Can I somehow make this automatically, so when someone issue an `apt-get install my-package` apt automatically installs the 3.2.2 version from my repository?

Comment: Are you aware that you can [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/783455/edit) your question and add that information into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done with just the dependencies on your package. Without special configuration, `apt-get` always prefers the highest version available, so, even if your package depends on `python-cherrypy3 (<< 3.2.5)`, it will pick the highest version of `python-cherrypy3` available. And since [Ubuntu 15.10 and above have only 3.5.0+](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-cherrypy3), that's what you'll get.

What you can do is provide a 3.2.5 version packaged of `python-cherrypy3` in your personal repository, which uses [an epoch number](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441879/158442), so that it is preferred over the newer package. Then depend on that.