# What is the relationship between Ubuntu's version of Kodi and its developer's version?

Tags: apt, ppa, versions, kodi

I installed `kodi` from the standard repositories (Ubuntu 16.04 xenial):

```
# apt show kodi
Package: kodi
Version: 2:16.1~git20160424.1410-final-0wily
```

The [web site for kodi](https://kodi.tv/) states that the latest version is `16.1 "Jarvis"`.

**What is the relationship between these two version numbers?**

The install wiki [mentions](http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_for_Linux#Installing_Kodi_on_Ubuntu-based_distributions) that one can use the team PPA but I do not know whether the versions diverge.

Comment: Both versions are the same, you can see they are both 16.1, AFAIK there is no difference as Kodi has moved on in development, I have not had an update for a while. I can't really find anything to back this up though but Kodi 17 went alpha a while ago and is getting a lot of development, so only bug fixes for 16.1, for updates (if there is any) the kodi PPA will get it first.

Comment: Ah, correct - I was fixed on the `2:` part of the version and did not realize the this is 16.1 in both cases. Would you mind just turning your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: You can accept the answer below if you like, he did a good job explaining the 2: for you :)

Comment: @MarkKirby Write your own answer. I thought you weren't checking this question that's why wrote the answer. I can delete mine :)

Comment: @Anwar It is fine, I was just leaving a passing comment. All I can say is "They are the same version", your answer is better than mine would of been.

Comment: The interesting thing is I'm also using Xenial and I'm only getting `15.2` as the highest, which matches with [this](https://launchpad.net/xbmc/+packages). 16.1 is only made available for yakkety users. I don't know how You get `16.1` from standard repository though. Are you sure you weren't using any PPA?

Comment: @Anwar: I use the standard repos only, just one PPA for `systemd`. I checked with `apt-cache policy` to make sure something has not sneaked in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both versions are `16.1` and are very close at least (if not exact version). The number `2` before `16.1` separated by `:` is called an *epoch*, and sometimes used to distinguish versioning of packages with two very diverse development track.

Read more about this special number here [Why do some packages have extra numbers on the front of their version string?](https://askubuntu.com/q/441879/61218)